# How to use / (slash), without using it as a path in React routing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

A name of one item in my array is name for example: `"apples/oranges?"` and I use this name as an id so I can use it as a page route as well to render a different page and the slash is creating a problem with routing.

How can I use the slash simple as a text?

Comment: You can't, really. It'd be better to replace the `"/"` in the name with just about any other character. Do you have a [mcve] for the route and path you are trying to match and use these types of values on? Or I can try to provide an example if you are looking how to start?

Comment: Oh ok I though I could use it somehow, thank you tho! I'm using "/" as my root directory so this name (apples/oranges), just renders the page on the root directory

Comment: Do you have more than the one route on `"/"`?

Comment: the root directory is "/" and every other directory starts with "/" and then the name of the directory like for example "/about"

Comment: Kindly do review your question before posting it and elaborate it better so we can understand your question.. You have a typo mistake "broblem".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you cannot use a path segment value that contains the `"/"` path segment character, you'd need to replace the `"/"` character with a different character, i.e. change `"apples/oranges"` to `"apples-oranges"` so it could be assigned to a single path param.

The exception is [Splats](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats).

Example:

```
<Route path="/*" element={<MyComponent />} />
```

Then in the component access the "splat" via the `useParams` hook:

```
const { "*": name } = useParams();
```

With the above, if the current path is `"/apples/oranges"` and ***no other*** route matches, then the `MyComponent` component will render and the `name` param will have the value `"apples/oranges"`.

[image: Edit how-to-use-slash-without-using-it-as-a-path-in-react-routing]

[image]

Example code:

```
import { Routes, Route, Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  const { "*": name } = useParams();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <div>Name: {name}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/apples">Apples</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/oranges">Oranges</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/apples/oranges">Apples/Oranges</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/*" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<h1>About</h1>} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To avoid path collisions you might also consider "name spacing" them into a sub-route.

```
<Routes>
  ...
  <Route path="/name/*" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/about" element={<h1>About</h1>} />
  ... any other non-"/name" routes ...
</Routes>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaning and taking a time to answer! This helped a lot!